# how to create a List of int entered on 1 line of the console

Tags: java, list, int

The idea is that I want to enter numbers from the console and put them directly into a List. That's my way but it does not work. I have no idea how to fix it. I tried manually importing java.util...., but it still does not work.

[image]

And that is the code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine()
            .split(" "))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


}
```

}

Comment: Please post code as text and not as image.

Comment: I want to show exeption!

Comment: It's not an exception, it's a compiler error!

Comment: ok ... "compiler error"

Comment: But if I show the code : 
 List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine()
                .split(" "))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());u
can you tell me where is mistake

Comment: We can see errors by copying and pasting your code. As long as you provide it as a text that is.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the last line as it follows:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine()
                           .split(" "))
                           .map(Integer::parseInt)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: oooo have to be just "map", not "mapToInt" 10x

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the answer you where looking for please accept it.